# Are "monolithic" and "homogeneous" really synonyms?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, meaning-in-context, synonyms

The thesaurus gives the two adjectives as synonymous. But I wonder if they are context specific? Am I right to doubt their being absolute synonymy?

Comment: Synonyms are words that mean *almost* the same thing.  In some senses.

Answer (score 2):

These are the definitions Google gives me after searching "definition monolithic" and "definition homogenous":

**Monolithic (Google)**

1. Formed of a single block of stone
2. (of an organization or system) large, powerful, and intractably indivisible and uniform.

Synonyms: inflexible, rigid, unbending, unchanging, fossilized

**Homogenous (Google)**

1. Of the same kind; alike
2. consisting of parts all of the same kind
3. (math) containing terms all of the same degree.

Synonyms: uniform, identical, unvaried, consistent, indistinguishable, homologous, ...

Furthermore, here are the wiktionary entries:

**Monolithic (Wiktionary)**

1. Of or resembling a monolith
2. Having a massive, unchanging structure that does not permit individual variation
3. (computing, said of an operating system's kernel) consisting of a single program using a single memory-addressing space

**Homogenous (Wiktionary)**

1. Of the same kind; alike, similar
2. Having the same composition throughout; of uniform make-up
3. (chemistry) in the same state of matter
4. (mathematics) Of which the properties of a smaller set apply to the whole; scalable

I hope this is enough to clear things up. Thesaurus probably declared them as synonyms since they are remotely similar, but I wouldn't really use them interchangeably. While homogenous means that something is built up uniformly, monolithic goes further and means that it is one single piece.

Comment: I too am struggling to see how they could be considered synonyms. And if you go into Google's thesaurus for each of them neither brings up the other as synonym. The only word they both bring up, which I noticed, was *uniform*.

Comment: This is a good answer, but it would be stronger if you linked to the pages in Google and Wiktionary that are the sources of your information. If you add those links, I will happily upvote your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Homogeneous means that any portion of something is the same as any other portion.  It doesn't exclude the possibility of being divisible into parts though, as long as the parts are all the same.

Monolithic means that something can not be divided into parts.  It doesn't require that all portions of it be the same, only that they can't be divided from one another.